# Verify trigonometry equation $\frac{\sin(A)}{\sin(A) + \cos(A)}=\frac{\sec(A)}{\sec(A)+\cos(A)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How would I verify the following trig equation?
$$\frac{\sin(A)}{\sin(A) + \cos(A)}=\frac{\sec(A)}{\sec(A)+\cos(A)}$$

My work so far is to write the RHS as
$$\frac{1/\cos(A)}{1/\cos(A) + \cos(A)}$$

But I am not sure what I can do to prove the identity.

Comment: What you have is incorrect. For instance, take $A=0$, the LHS evaluates to $0$ while the RHS gives us $\dfrac12$.

Comment: There is nothing you can do to prove the identity, because it is not a identity.

Comment: Maybe the $\cos$ on the RHS of the identity should be $\csc$?

Comment: I wrote It out of the book I am using.

Comment: Well the typo is not on my part but on the book I am using.

Comment: Extra points for finding a typo. :-).

Comment: Is this question from any book? If yes then mention it.

Comment: it is in schaums outlines of trigonometry page 93 problem 8.38

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\frac{a}{a+x} = \frac{b}{b+x}$, and you have that $x\neq 0$ (and the denominators too), then multiplying across and canceling
 will give $a=b$.

So, the equation is satisfied only if $\sin A = \frac{1}{\cos A}$, which is impossible.

Comment: so would I cross multiply?

Comment: You can do what you want, but the formula as stated will never be true.

Answer (score 0):

I assume there is a typo:
$$\dfrac{\sin(A)}{\sin(A) + \cos(A)}=\dfrac{\sec(A)}{\sec(A)+\csc(A)}$$

Divide numerator & denominator by ${\sin(A)},$ and use that $\frac{1}{\sin(A)} = \csc(A)$:

$$\frac{\sin(A)}{\sin(A) + \cos(A)} = \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{\sin(A)} \cos(A)} = \frac{1}{1 + \csc(A) \cos(A)}$$

Now, multiply numerator & denominator by by $\sec(A),$ and use the fact $\sec(A) \cos(A) = 1$ :
$$ \frac{\sec(A)}{\sec(A) + \csc(A) } $$